# Can't parse JSON properly - access to inner list values

Tags: apex, json, list, apexrest, parsing

for two days, i am trying to figure out parsing of following json.

```
[
    {
        "name": "Czech Republic",
        "alpha2Code": "CZ",
        "alpha3Code": "CZE",
        "capital": "Prague",
        "subregion": "Central Europe",
        "region": "Europe",
        "regionalBlocs": [
            {
                "acronym": "EU",
                "name": "European Union"
            }
        ],
        "independent": false
    }
]
```

My wrapper:

```
public with sharing class Countries_info {

    public String name;
    public String alpha2Code;
    public String alpha3Code;
    public String capital;
    public String subregion;
    public String region;
    public List<RegionalBlocs> regionalBlocs;
    
    public class RegionalBlocs {
        public String acronym;
    }
    
    public static List<Countries_info> parse(String json) {
        return (List<Countries_info>) System.JSON.deserialize(json, List<Countries_info>.class);
    }
}
```

And Retriever

```
public with sharing class Countries_Info_Retriever {

private static final String restcountries_URL = 'https://restcountries.com/v2/all?fields=name,alpha2Code,alpha3Code,capital,region,subregion,regionalBlocs';
private static final String Get = 'GET';
public static List<Countries_info> getCountriesData() {
    List<Countries_info> countriesInfo = new List<Countries_info>();
    Http httpCallout = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(restcountries_URL);
    req.setMethod(Get);

    HttpResponse countriesResponse = httpCallout.send(req);
    List<Countries_info> restcountriesResponse = Countries_info.parse(countriesResponse.getBody());

    for (Countries_info block : restcountriesResponse) {
        system.debug(block.name + ' ' + block.capital + ' ' + block.regionalBlocs.acronym);
    }
    return countriesInfo;
}
```

}

and for the love of god, I can't figure out how to get to that **acronym**. I can print out the whole List(regionalBlocs). but can't access the acronym value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[]` is a *list* of items, so you just need to access the zeroth index:

```
block.regionalBlocs[0].acronym
```

Alternatively, you can also loop over the `regionalBlocs` data:

```
for(Countries_info.RegionalBlocs regionalBloc: block.regionalBlocs) {
  system.debug(block.name + ' ' + block.capital + ' ' + regionalBloc.acronym);
}
```

This would get you all of the acronyms provided.

Comment: Thanks, I am so dumb :D the first version works fine. The 2nd will only get me access to regionalBloc.acronym, the others stays unreachable :-/